# Convert piecewise function with ranges to a single mathematical formula

Tags: piecewise-continuity

For a programming task (an SQL expression) I need a function made of mathematical operators ($+$, $-$, $*$, $floor$, $ceil$, and comparison operators returning value $0$ (false) or $1$ (true)...) that maps a real value into 4 discrete values depending on 3 boundary values $a$, $b$, $c$ where $a < b < c$ and $x > 0$:

$$f(x, a, b, c) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x \lt a$}\\
1, & \text{if $a \le x \lt b$}\\
2, & \text{if $b \le x \lt c$}\\
3, & \text{if $x \ge c$}
\end{cases}
$$

In SQL a `CASE` operator exists but but I want to avoid if because one constraint I have is the $x$ is in itself a complex expression, so the function should have $x$ mentioned just once.

As an example of the thing I need but with the simpler case of a single boundary value, for
$$
f(x, a) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x \lt a$}\\
1, & \text{if $x \ge a$}
\end{cases}
$$
the formula is:
$f(x, a) = x \lt a$

Comment: How about $f(x)=(x\ge a)+(x\ge b)+(x\ge c)$? Does that work?

Comment: For what it's worth, there is the Heaviside step function but it's just if/else in the end anyway. You can then just sum a list of them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function